# Wireless is disabled by hardware switch on sony vaio

Tags: wireless, vaio, sony

I have Sony VAIO VPCEB26FG. I installed ubuntu 11.04. When i switch on my wireless button only bluetooth gets activated and it shows wireless is disabled by hardware switch. I tried using command $sudo rfkill list. The output of which is

```
kiran@sytem:~$ rfkill list  
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
2: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
3: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

How to solve this problem??

Comment: Try to look in the BIOS settings the internal devices that are controlled by the switch. Report back if you see anything.

Comment: nothing in BIOS settings...

Comment: Instead of commenting back here, I posted an answer. Please read it and post any follow-up comments on it.

Comment: I have same issue I had windows 7 but didn't work so I had to use portable ubuntu boot It worked fine for months...but now i have same issue and I have no idea anything about commands Someone give me a instructions for like a noob ( me )

Answer (score 5):

This solved my problem on my Vaio vpceg:

```
sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Place this above the `exit 0` line:

```
rfkill unblock wifi
rfkill unblock all
sudo modprobe -r acer_wmi
```

Answer (score 2):

I will ask you to try this, which once consisted of a temporary fix to a problem I had:

1. Turn the **switch off**
2. Run `rfkill block wifi`
3. Turn the **switch on** now
4. Run `rfkill unblock wifi`

When I did this, my wifi started working. However, rebooting my computer would kill wifi again. My workaround consisted in blacklisting a module called `dell_laptop`, which was problematic and was blocking my wifi.

So, please run this command and comment what is output, `lsmod | grep sony`.
If the module `sony_laptop` is loaded, you should proceed to blacklist it, and reboot your computer.

To *blacklist* a module, run the following command:

```
sudo echo "blacklist sony_laptop" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Which is just a way of appending the echoed line to the file referenced. You might as well do it with your text editor of choice.

If you wonder where am I getting all this voodoo from, check this [bug report at Gnome Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624271).

Comment: I dont know what solved my problem, before i use the commands you mentioned, my wifi was working and i can see enable wireless option. However wireless networks option is still disabled. Also there is a module sony_laptop in my laptop. Can you tell me how to blacklist it or refer any link?

Comment: I think it is mentioned in the Gnome Bugzilla link, but I added some instructions there for you.

Comment: Thanks alot Mr. Wolter Hellmund. I hope this will solve my problem permanently.

Comment: This is how it looks now yfrog.com/nh7xyp Now how can i search for available wireless networks with wireless networks option disabled.

Comment: There is no "search" function for wireless networks, if you are sure you are within a wireless network, I recommend you to either use the "Connect to a hidden wireless network" or attempt a connection from another computer. There may be a better method, but I am not very experienced with wifi debugging. Have you rebooted the computer to see if the blacklisting worked as a permanent solution?

Comment: Blacklisting didn't work, after i rebooted again that "wireless is disabled by hardware switch" bug appeared again. Blocking and unblocking wifi with rfkill didn't work too.

Comment: Thats a great shame, you don't remember what you did before it started working?

Comment: I have found that, if i keep wireless switch on at the time of boot there will not be above error and if i keep wireless switch off at time of boot it will show 'wireless is disabled by hardware switch'.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used a Sony Vaio, but other laptops I've used have a function key to disable/enable wireless.  It's usually accessed with a "Fn" key in conjunction with some function that is the same color as the Fn key (often blue).

Also, the BIOS often has a setting you can change at boot time.  There could be one that makes it default to disabled until enabled.

Comment: i checked BIOS settings but i didn't find anything related to wireless there.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo echo "blacklist sony_laptop" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

seems to work for me. Also, the switch seemed to be tricky and the wi-fi would go out and the switch needs to be flipped occasionally.