# Have internet connectivity, but can't select wireless networks (Fresh install)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager, internet

I am using Ubuntu 17 and just installed it. I have internet connectivity, but when I try to select a wireless network, I am getting the message that there are no networks in range.

`$ me@home:~$ lspci | grep Wireless`

gives the following:

`09:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)`

Comment: Try this answer from a similar question https://askubuntu.com/a/982474/19626 . Do a search for "AR9287", and you will see that you are not the first to have problems with this hardware.

Comment: You must be connected to a wired ethernet then? Or is the wireless somehow connecting & authenticating, without letting you see or choose?

Comment: @Xen2050 I was able to choose all this stuff during the installation process, but now I can't change wireless networks.

Comment: That's different - so when running live the wifi works well, but after installing it's now locked/frozen...

Comment: It's functioning fine, though. I am on the internet, wirelessly, through the wireless adapter. However, I can't disconnect from it, or connect to a different network. I am being told there are no nearby networks, when there is obviously at least one, and there are tons more that aren't visible either.